# The Inverse Function Theorem - proof

Tags: real-analysis

I am trying to undresteam Inverse Function Theorem so I googled and found a book

> Calculus on Manifolds  by Michael Spivak

I was happy because I have proof here but I got stuck in first paragraph. Can anyone help me with this equation? I really don't get why it is equal. I tried to do this by definition of frechet's derivative but I got stuck in welter of symbols.

Here is the theorem :
[image]
And here is part of the proof which i don't understand (underlined)
[image]
Just why $D(\lambda^{-1})(f(a)) = \lambda^{-1}$ ?

For me it is just : $D(\lambda^{-1})(f(a)) = D((Df(a))^{-1})(f(a)) $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because in general, if $L: (E,\| \cdot \|) \to (F,\|\cdot \|)$ is a continuous linear map, then for any $x \in E$, $DL(x) = L$.

It is because:

$$\frac{1}{\|h\|}\| L(x+h) - L(x) - L(h)\| = 0 \to 0$$

Comment: Thank you, thats 100% right and... easy!
I will accept the answer as soon as I can (6 min more ).